# Cover all possibilities to click / touch with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, click, touch, tap

Is it possible to write the following, in order to cover all eventualities in terms of making something clickable on desktop and mobile (with jQuery Mobile)?

```js
$('.persOpen').on('click vclick tap', function() {
    
    // do stuff
  
  });
```

Comment: Tap makes use of vclick and therefore should be used with caution on touch devices. https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/

Comment: Use vclick with caution on touch devices. Webkit based browsers synthesize mousedown, mouseup, and click events roughly 300ms after the touchend event is dispatched. https://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/

Comment: I did use just click but got a lot of feedback that it doesn't work on certain mobile devices. For all the devices I tested it was fine, but apparently "in the real world" it's not very stable... hence the question.